# S3 server access logs VS S3 object-level logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to set up logging for my AWS S3 buckets.

I ran accross this AWS Config rule [s3-bucket-logging-enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-logging-enabled.html). The logs here are server access logs.

From the CIS AWS Foundations 1.5.0 I also need to set up [object-level logging for read events](https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_Amazon_Web_Services_Foundations_v1.5.0_L2.audit:0226ee7f70236729e294db879394e0da).

I found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/logging-with-S3.html) in S3 doc about logging options. I just can't get my head around this. Can anyone help me understand if server access logs and object-level logs are different or the same and what service I must use between S3 server logs, CloudTrail and Cloudwatch.

I am also not sure about what log type does the Config rule check.

Thank you for your time

Comment: The difference between those two logging types is displayed in a helpful table here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/logging-with-S3.html